# How do I use a declared java type(a class) in my Xtext project

Tags: xtext, xtend

I want to use some data type created by me(they are created in another project) in a new xtext project.
For example if I have some classes like the following:
//java project

```
class A {
 int a;
 String b;
 // getters & setters
 void f(){...}
}
```

In the xtext project I would like to use them as a type for some variables, but I would also like to use the primitive types as well (string, int, boolean).

So in the test file after launching the java eclipse app, I could be able to use them as the following

```
variable t = new A();
t.f()
t.getB()...
```

Comment: did you hhave a look at xbase (see Five simple steps to your JVM language  https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/104_jvmdomainmodel.html)

Comment: This is not solving my problem, I already have a certain grammar for my xtext project, but I want to use some java classes as a type and also to be able to have suggestions, after I press t. methods f() and getB() should be there and so on...

Comment: i stil dont understand. xbase can do that.

Comment: Ok, so I have a project with class models wrote in java, also I have a xtext project with a grammar that has nothing to do with the first project. But I want somehow to link them, for example in my java project I have the class A and I want to use it in the xtext project with all of it's methods, but I don't what to write a model again for it, I want to import it in order to be able to use it in xtext project.

Comment: please give the tutorial a try and try to use your class files from the dmodel files (you need to put them on the classpath though)

Comment: Those java classes are not in the dmodel, this is what I told you. I have them on a different project and I don't know how to import them in order to use them as I said before. Also I don't want to rewrite the grammar, I want to be able to use those classes just as a type, like  "var myVar = new A()", where A is the class from the project I want to import. I don't want to create a new grammar for classes.

Comment: you can reference java types in the dmodel: you are not restricted to String & co, you also can use MyPojo